# Using vm.$set on bi-dimentional array

Tags: vue.js

I have this array :

```
      puzzleGrid: [ 
        [ { "coordinates": { "x": 0, "y": 0 }, "state": { "free": true, "label": "" } }, 
          { "coordinates": { "x": 1, "y": 0 }, "state": { "free": false, "label": 4 } }, 
          { "coordinates": { "x": 2, "y": 0 }, "state": { "free": false, "label": 2 } } ],
        [ { "coordinates": { "x": 0, "y": 1 }, "state": { "free": false, "label": 6 } }, 
          { "coordinates": { "x": 1, "y": 1 }, "state": { "free": false, "label": 5 } }, 
          { "coordinates": { "x": 2, "y": 1 }, "state": { "free": false, "label": 8 } } ], 
        [ { "coordinates": { "x": 0, "y": 2 }, "state": { "free": false, "label": 3 } }, 
          { "coordinates": { "x": 1, "y": 2 }, "state": { "free": false, "label": 7 } }, 
          { "coordinates": { "x": 2, "y": 2 }, "state": { "free": false, "label": 1 } } ] 
      ]
```

And I want to update this part :

```
[this.puzzleGrid[y][x].state, this.puzzleGrid[y + 1][x].state] = [this.puzzleGrid[y + 1][x].state, this.puzzleGrid[y][x].state];
```

But I want it to be reactive so i need to use **vm.$set()** to do so. I'm kinda lost on how to translate the parameters needed to use **vm.$set(vm.items, indexOfItem, newValue)**.

Appreciate any help, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can take a few approaches to deal with this:

1. You could treat it like an array you want to update, in this case
   you could do something like this: `vm.$set(this.puzzleGrid[0], 0, {
   "coordinates": { "x": 3, "y": 0 }, "state": { "free": false,
   "label": 2 } });` which will replace the entire object from
   `this.puzzleGrid[0][0]` with `{ "coordinates": { "x": 3, "y": 0 },
   "state": { "free": false, "label": 2 } }`.
2. You could update an object contained in the array directly, doing something like this:
   `this.$set(this.puzzleGrid[0][0], 'state', { "free": false, "label":
   4 })` which will replace the value on `state` with this: `{ "free":
   false, "label": 4 }` on the object contained in `this.puzzleGrid[0][0]`.
3. Also update property by property on an object of the array:
   `this.$set(this.puzzleGrid[0][0]['state'], 'free', false)`.

Comment: Exactly what I needed Thank you !

Comment: happy to help! if it solve your issue can you accept the answer as correct, please?